# SWF Debug details

Tags: flash, apache-flex, flashdevelop

I am trying to view SWF file details (like from which path it was compiled).
This SWF was created using flex SDK.

Where and how can I see the debug details of the SWF file?

Comment: Why would you need to know the path from which a SWF was compiled?

Comment: I would like to secure my SWF file,
and I eared that there are many unnecessary details attached to the SWF file.
for removing those details I just needed to change the debug option to false on the config.xml

Comment: Please post your solution as a formal answer.  When creating a production Build; Flash Builder has an "Export release Build" option which may have been what you're looking for.

Comment: I recently discovered a need to view this information as well.  FlashDevelop suddenly stopped hitting breakpoints for no apparent reason, and I'm wondering if it's because Flash compiled the wrong source code file paths into the debug SWF, possibly as a result of compiling via commandline + JSFL script.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Adobe Scout for your problem, please find attached screenshot for a detailed report generated from the tool.[image]

Answer (score 1):

Did you try to use debug version of Flash Player? It provides lots of debug functionality. Also, you can retrieve many interesting information with decompilers (for example, Sothink SWF Decompiler).

Answer (score 1):

I used adobe SWF investigator,

Thank you all